# How to include all source files from folder? (C++, MS VS 2013)

Tags: c++, syntax, include

I have simple project where I use tiny [ttmath library](http://www.ttmath.org/) for C++ (big nums).
This library consists of 13 *.h files.
I have included all these files in a stupid way:

```
 #include "ttmath\ttmath.h"
 #include "ttmath\ttmathbig.h"
 #include "ttmath\ttmathdec.h"
 #include "ttmath\ttmathint.h"
 #include "ttmath\ttmathmisc.h"
 #include "ttmath\ttmathobjects.h"
 #include "ttmath\ttmathparser.h"
 #include "ttmath\ttmaththreads.h"
 #include "ttmath\ttmathtypes.h"
 #include "ttmath\ttmathuint.h"
 #include "ttmath\ttmathuint_noasm.h"
 #include "ttmath\ttmathuint_x86.h"
 #include "ttmath\ttmathuint_x86_64.h"
```

What is the right way? I expect smth like this:

```
#include "ttmath\*.h"
```

but can not find...

Comment: Are you sure that you really need to include all those files?

Comment: @gurka Maybe it is not necessary. But for my question it doesn't importnat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the right way? I expect smth like this:
>
> `#include "ttmath\*.h"`
>
> but can not find...

That won't work because the preprocessor is not going to expand characters to match things in the way you expect wildcards to work.

My recommendation would be to create a single custom header file of your own, and place all the `#include` entries in there. For example, in your `.c` file, you can add your own header:

```
#include "my_header.h"
```

And the contents of `my_header.h` would be:

```
#include "ttmath\ttmath.h"
#include "ttmath\ttmathbig.h"
#include "ttmath\ttmathdec.h"
#include "ttmath\ttmathint.h"
#include "ttmath\ttmathmisc.h"
#include "ttmath\ttmathobjects.h"
#include "ttmath\ttmathparser.h"
#include "ttmath\ttmaththreads.h"
#include "ttmath\ttmathtypes.h"
#include "ttmath\ttmathuint.h"
#include "ttmath\ttmathuint_noasm.h"
#include "ttmath\ttmathuint_x86.h"
#include "ttmath\ttmathuint_x86_64.h"
```

Basically, you put everything in a single header, and include that one instead.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor doesn't have an "include all" built into it. Neither does it accept wildcards in filenames. You'll have to manually include all of them.

A common solution is to place all the includes in a new .h file and include that one every time you need all of them.